# Emscripten - Is there a way to abort execution from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, emscripten

When executing a long-running function (including `Module.callMain`), is there a way to abort execution from JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way is to run the WebAssembly in a worker thread and terminate the entire thread from the main thread.  You cannot terminate an individual WebAssembly function.